# Como receber informações do firebase em um ion-select?

Tags: ionic, apache, apache-cordova, firebase

Olá, estou com dificuldade de recuperar informações já armazenadas em outro cadastros em um ion-select. Em um cadastro anterior o Local já é cadastrado e em um segundo cadastro gostaria de receber em um ion-select uma lista de todos os Locais que já foram cadastrados antes.

Preciso apenas dos nomes dos Locais e que seja possível salvar esse nome. em item.local. Segue código que está salvando manualmente sem resgatar do banco so option.

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-label>Local</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="item.local" placeholder="Local">
        <ion-option value="Frente 1">Frente 1</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="Frente 2">Frente 2</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="Frente 3">Frente 3</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="Frente 4">Frente 4</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="Frente 5">Frente 5</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Essa seria a resposta, para quem estiver em dificuldade como eu estava.

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Status</ion-label>
      <ion-select  [(ngModel)]="item.status" placeholder="Status">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let status of statusList$ | async" value={{status.name}}>{{status.name}}</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>>
```